# Как правильно оптимизировать запросы к БД в eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть следующий код:

```
$cat = 'gadgets';
$category = Category::where('categories.alias', '=', $cat)
            ->firstOrFail();
$childrenCategories = Category::where('parent_id', '=', $category->id)->get();
```

Т.е. в `$category` мы получаем саму категорию. Далее, в `$childrenCategories` мы получаем все дочерние категории, т.е. те, у которых `parent_id` = ID категории.

Вопрос: каким образом можно это оптимизировать, сделав 1 запрос к БД вместо двух?

Заранее спасибо! Всех с наступающим!

Answer (score 1):

Если в модели Category вы определите следующее отношение:

```
public function childrens()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

то вы сможете получить категорию с ее подкатегориями одной строкой кода:

```
$category = Category::with('childrens')
    ->where('alias', '=', $cat)
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Хотя фактически к БД будет сделано два запроса.